# atribuir value ao input angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic3

Tenho um objeto vindo do banco que mostro na view em um ngFor.

o que pretendo é passsar este [value] para o componente para salvar no banco e não estou sabendo como.

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let item of dados">
      <ion-input type="hidden" [value]="item.nomeProduto"></ion-input>
      <h2>{{item.nomeProduto}}</h2>

  </div>
  <button ion-button full block color="danger">CADASTRAR</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

tente fazer com `[ngValue]` ao invés de `[value]`